# How to I filter summed rows with a condition in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I essentially want to display only those features in the dataset that have number of null values > 0.

The line of code:

```
train_df.isnull().sum()
```

Output is:

```
Id                  0
MSSubClass          0
MSZoning            0
LotFrontage       259
LotArea             0
Street              0
Alley            1369
...
```

I am unable to modify the code to show only the features where the values in more than 0 (or any other condition).

Thank you!

Comment: `train_df.isnull().sum().to_frame('sum').query('sum > 0')`

Comment: Hi @cs95 your line showed the following error: "NumExprClobberingError: Variables in expression "(sum) > (0)" overlap with builtins: ('sum')", so I replaced "sum" with "sum1" and it worked fine!

Comment: I believe you meant to say non-null values > 0...

Comment: Yes it was clashing with the built-in sum function. Good work getting it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
d = dict(Id        = 0,
MSSubClass         = 0,
MSZoning           = 0,
LotFrontage        = 259,
LotArea            =  0,
Street             =  0,
x               = -1,
Alley            = 1369)
df = pd.DataFrame([d],index=['value']).transpose()
df
```

output

```
            value
Id          0
MSSubClass  0
MSZoning    0
LotFrontage 259
LotArea     0
Street      0
x           -1
Alley       1369
```

To filter non-null values > 0 :

```
df[df.value > -1]
```